# How to print a random choice string as a label in Tkinter window?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *
import random 

root = Tk()

frame1 = Frame(root, width = 400, height = 600)
greet = Label(random.choice(("Hi", "Hello")))
frame1.pack(side=TOP)
greet.pack()
```

So Actually I want something like this When I Run it should print a label because it can't print like a variable so I tried it. Is there Any other way of printing it in the Tkinter window as label?

Comment: Try this:
    greet = Label(root,text=random.choice(["Hi", "Hello"]))

Comment: Are you asking how to compute a random choice, or how to configure a label widget? Both are well documented.

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign the string to print to the `text` property of the label

```
from tkinter import *
import random 

root = Tk()

frame1 = Frame(root, width = 400, height = 600)
greet = Label(text=random.choice(("Hi", "Hello")))
frame1.pack(side=TOP)
greet.pack()

root.mainloop()
```